# WebSphere NameNotFoundException occurred on an indirect lookup on the name java: comp/env/jdbc/bar

Tags: java, jdbc, websphere-8

I am deployng a java `war` on websphere 8.5 but I have some trouble creating and using JDBC datasource.

This is the `ibm-web-bnd.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-bnd xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-bnd_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
  <virtual-host name="default_host"/>
  <resource-ref binding-name="jdbc/foobar" name="jdbc/bar"/>
</web-bnd>
```

And this is the error log on websphere:

```
[5/19/17 11:17:21:137 UTC] 00000095 SystemOut     O [TEMPLATE-MYCOMPANY-WP]2017-05-19 11:17:21,137 ERROR [WebContainer : 6]  taaccess.provider.JNDIConnectionProvider: 
Cannot get connection: com.ibm.websphere.naming.CannotInstantiateObjectException: 
A NameNotFoundException occurred on an indirect lookup on the name java:comp/env/jdbc/bar. 
The name java:comp/env/jdbc/bar maps to a JNDI name in deployment descriptor bindings for the application performing the JNDI lookup. 
Make sure that the JNDI name mapping in the deployment descriptor binding is correct. 
If the JNDI name mapping is correct, make sure the target resource can be resolved with the specified name relative to the default initial context.  
[Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: DefaultCell01/nodes/DefaultNode01/servers/server1, name: jdbc/foobar: First component in name foobar not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]]
```

My websphere datasource is configured a follow (and test connection is working)

- Name: `foo_bar`
- JNDI name: `jdbc_foobarlocal`
- Scope: `Node=DefaultNode01,Server=server1`
- Provider: `Oracle JDBC Driver`

Is the `ibm-web-bnd.xml` getting ignored during deployment or I have to modify my datasource?

Comment: You have bad JNDI name, as `jdbc_foobarlocal` is not `jdbc/foobar` that you are using in the binding file. Fix one or the other.

Comment: I should use binding-name or name from my ibm-web-bnd.xml?

Comment: The `ibm-web-bnd.xml` provides mapping between reference that you use in the code - I assume it is `java:comp/env/jdbc/bar` and the actual JNDI name configured for that resource in the server configuration - in your case it is currently `jdbc_foobarlocal`. So you have two options, either keep JNDI name as is, and modify xml setting `binding-name=jdbc_foobarlocal` or change the JNDI name on datasource to `jdbc/foobar`.

Comment: @Gas your comment clears all my doubt. Thanks.

Comment: I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ibm-web-bnd.xml` provides mapping between reference that you use in the code - I assume it is `java:comp/env/jdbc/bar` - and the actual JNDI name configured for that resource in the server configuration - in your case it is currently `jdbc_foobarlocal`. So you have two options, either keep JNDI name as is, and modify xml setting `binding-name=jdbc_foobarlocal` or change the JNDI name on datasource to `jdbc/foobar`.